# Data changes when working with classes

Tags: programming, arduino-mega

When I pass an array, and it's len to the constructor of a class. I store the length, and access it later, it's value changes, seemingly at random.

```
#include "Arduino.h"

#define NUMSENSORS 2
const byte dataPins[] = {A5, A4};

class B {
    public:
        B(byte pin) { _pin = pin; }
        byte getPin() { return _pin; }
    private:
        byte _pin;
};

class A {
    public:
        A(const byte sensorPins[], int len) {
            Serial.print("provided len is: ");
            Serial.println(len);
            _len = len;
            Serial.print("Stored len is: ");
            Serial.println(_len);
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) { myBarray[i] = new B(sensorPins[i]); }
        }
        B* myBarray[];
        int _len;
        void printLen() {
            Serial.print("Length is: ");
            Serial.println(_len);
        }
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    A test(dataPins, NUMSENSORS);
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<10; i++) {
        test.printLen();
        delay(100);
    }
}

void loop() {
}
```

The value of len is fine in the constructor,  but is different when I call it in the function "getLen".

I feel as though it has something to do with pointers. Because if I comment out the for loop in the constructor of A, the value is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `B* myBarray[];` has no size, and no memory allocated to it. Where do you think you are copying the data to?

Comment: I  thought that the memory would be allocated when I call the new B(sensorPins[i])... am I wrong? And why would that affect the value of A::_len in the later call?

Comment: No, B is allocated when you call new B(). The array is not allocated - ever - so it resides at address 0. Any writes to it will overwrite any other variables that have been allocated in that area, such as A.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. So how would I fix it? Sorry, but I am fairly new to c++

Comment: Either pre-allocate it with a fixed (maximum) size, or use `malloc()` to allocate the right amount of bytes to the array - that is, `_len * sizeof(B)` bytes.

Comment: Forcing a max length of the array worked! Thanks a lot. I'm going to have to look at malloc () to figure it out. so I can dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: There seems to be something missing here. What is the intention of the A and B class? They actually do no add anything as all the info you are using is in the dataPins vector and NUMSENSORS.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do this with a template class and avoid malloc, etc.

```
#define membersof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

const byte dataPins[] = { A5, A4 };

class B {
public:
  byte getPin() { return (_pin); }
  void setPin(byte pin) { _pin = pin; }
private:
  byte _pin;
};

template<unsigned len>
class A {
public:
  A(const byte sensorPins[]) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++)
      _vec[i].setPin(sensorPins[i]);
  }
  unsigned getLen() { return (len); }
  B* getB(unsigned ix) { return (ix < len ? &_vec[ix] : NULL); }

private:
  B _vec[len];
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  A<membersof(dataPins)> test(dataPins);
  unsigned len = test.getLen();
  Serial.print(F("test.getLen()="));
  Serial.println(len);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    B* bp = test.getB(i);
    Serial.print(F("test::B["));
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(F("].getPin()="));
    Serial.println(bp->getPin());
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Cheers!